# MySQL select sum as given column

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a Table with 3 columns

```
|aaa | bbb | ccc|
|---------------|
|111 | 123 | uuu|
|333 | 234 | uuu|
|555 | 345 | nnn|
```

Now I select a sum like:

```
SELECT *, sum(bbb) as bbb from myTable GROUP BY ccc
```

I recive

```
|aaa | bbb | ccc | bbb|
|---------------------|
|333 | 234 | uuu | 357|
|555 | 345 | nnn | 345|
```

`bbb` is set new in output...

Is there a way to replace the column that exists so I get:

```
|aaa | bbb | ccc |
|----------------|
|333 | 357 | uuu |
|555 | 345 | nnn |
```

I know I could use an other name but using an other name is not the question :)

Comment: just do as `select aaa,sum(bbb) as bbb,ccc from myTable GROUP BY ccc`

Comment: Just modify the query to select the columns that you want.  But, you have a malformed `group by`, with a column in the `select` that is not in the `group by`.

Comment: the thing is there are about 25 columns... and typing everycolumn is kind of... annoing since I dont know if there will be some columns added in future ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add all columns you need to the select clause:

```
SELECT aaa, sum(bbb) as bbb,ccc from myTable GROUP BY ccc
```

Comment: the thing is there are about 25 columns... and typing everycolumn is kind of... annoing since I dont know if there will be some columns added in future ^^

Comment: There is no other way :(

Comment: Also no way to select all fields except one ?

Comment: Ok, ill accept this one as soons as i'm allowed :) thx anyways.

Comment: It's probably better to mention each column in the query anyway, then changes in the underlying database structure don't affect your application, allowing updates of the database structure before you roll out a new version of your application, reducing the amount of time your application is unusable.

Answer (score 3):

Don't include that column in the `SELECT` part of the query.

```
SELECT aaa, sum(bbb) as bbb, ccc from myTable GROUP BY ccc;
```

Comment: 1up because you were 20sec later than the other poster, otherwise I had accepted this one.